# Android checklist / to-do list app which can insert items anywhere

Tags: android, note-taking, productivity, knowledge-organization

I'm looking for an Android app with the following features:

1. Maintains a checklist / to-do list -- i.e. a list where items can be toggled, preferably with a single click. I don't really mind whether they're ticked, crossed out, greyed out, etc. as long as there are two states I can easily switch between.
2. Allows re-ordering, editing, and deletion of items.
3. Allows insertion of a new item directly **anywhere** in the list -- so if, for example, I want a new item at position 30 of an 80-item list, I don't have to add it at the bottom then drag it up through five screens.
4. Doesn't ask for excessive permissions (I can't think what a to-do list app should need beyond file access).

For some reason, (3) seems difficult to find: for example, ColorNote, Omni Notes, and Simple ToDo would all fit my needs except for the fact that they can only add items at the end of the list, as far as I can tell.

In addition, it would be nice (but not essential) to have the following:

1. Searching within lists.
2. A fairly lightweight specialized app, rather than a Swiss army chainsaw "I will organize your whole life and integrate with everything" affair with a to-do list as one of its hundred features.
3. Free (as in freedom) Software / Open Source.

Comment: I love [TackCoach](http://www.taskcoach.org/), which I use on Android & Windows & share the data via DropBox. Alas, it fails on #3, but, whatever you use, maybe you can be more structured? I don't have one list with 100 tasks, I have 6 or 8 lists, each with sub-lists and some with sub-sub-lists. Even if an item is entered at the end, you would only have to drag it past a few entries to get it where you want it. Please, do check out the [feature list](http://www.taskcoach.org/features.html) of TaskCoach, which is OFSS & runs on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, BSD, iPhone, iPad, and iPod Touch.